# Create functions to pack one widget and remove all others when different keys are pressed

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am making a controller for a car with Python and I was going to have 3 separate images to represent whether the wheels are turning left, right, or neutral. I need only one of these images to be shown at a time.

So far I have used bind to trigger functions because I haven't seen any other way to do so. I have looked into pack and pack_forget but I don't know how I could trigger them to be activated by *other* widgets (since I am using bind).

```
import tkinter as tk

win = tk.Tk()

def forwards(event):
    print("going forwards...")
def left(event):
    print("turning left...")
def right(event):
    print("turning right...")
def backwards(event):
    print("going backwards...")

neutralImage = tk.PhotoImage(file="neutral.gif")
leftImage = tk.PhotoImage(file="turnedLeft.gif")
rightImage = tk.PhotoImage(file="turnedRight.gif")

neutralPosition = tk.Label(win, image=neutralImage)
leftPosition = tk.Label(win, image=leftImage)
rightPosition = tk.Label(win, image=rightImage)

win.bind("w", forwards)
win.bind("a", left)
win.bind("d", right)
win.bind("s", backwards)
```

I have identified the problem as the following: I can't hide or show the widgets unless it is them that I press the button over.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of having three widgets what you can do is replace the image of the same widget when you need it.

```
import tkinter as tk

def changeImage(imageLabelWidget, newImage):
    imageLabelWidget.configure(image=newImage)
    imageLabelWidget.image = newImage

win = tk.Tk()
neutralImage = tk.PhotoImage(file="neutral.gif")
leftImage = tk.PhotoImage(file="turnedLeft.gif")
rightImage = tk.PhotoImage(file="turnedRight.gif")


neutralPosition = tk.Label(win, image=neutralImage)
neutralPosition.image = neutralImage
neutralPosition.pack()


win.bind("w", lambda event, imageLabelWidget=neutralPosition, newImage=neutralImage: 
                            changeImage(imageLabelWidget, newImage))
win.bind("a", lambda event, imageLabelWidget=neutralPosition, newImage=leftImage: 
                            changeImage(imageLabelWidget, newImage))
win.bind("d", lambda event, imageLabelWidget=neutralPosition, newImage=rightImage: 
                            changeImage(imageLabelWidget, newImage))

win.mainloop()
```

Comment: Hey man thank you so much for writing all that code for me. However, I get `AttributeError: 'Label' object has no attribute 'image'` when I try to run it. I'm really new to Python and I don't know how I could fix that. Would you mind explaining that? In fact I've been studying the code for a while now and I still don't really know what's going on here.

Comment: you were right, I had mistake in one attribute please review my answer again, I already edit it and test it.

Of course there is no problem, what we do with the changeImage function is to change the image attribute that the Label widget has with: `imageLabelWidget.configure (image = newImage)`, then what we do is assign the image again to that attribute, this we must do it because if not python garbage collector will delete the image and we will only see a blank space (this happens in old versions of tk and tcl).

Comment: and then what is done with the bind is to add the function of changing the image only that we do it with lambda to be able to pass arguments, otherwise as you have it in your post we could not, in this case you could save the arguments if you change the code to classes in this way both the images and the widget can become an attribute of the class.